# ping: connect: invalid argument

Tags: ping

Can someone explain this to me?

```
gbouras@master:~$ ping 10.0.0.12
ping: connect: Invalid argument
gbouras@master:~$ ping 10.0.0.11
PING 10.0.0.11 (10.0.0.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
```

I understand if 10.0.0.12 doesn't exist and I get a timeout error but I don't get why it would say "Invalid argument"

```
uname -a
Linux master 5.11.0-1022-gcp #24-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 21 07:40:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ping -V
ping from iputils 20210202
```

Comment: Does the `ping: connect: Invalid argument` error message reoccur if you push the button in back of the router to toggle the power off and then push it again to toggle the power back on?

Comment: What does `type -a ping` tell you? Is `ping` an alias, shell function, or a script, rather than an ELF binary at `/sbin/ping`?

Comment: `$type -a ping
ping is /usr/bin/ping
ping is /bin/ping`
this runs on GCP, created using their supplied ubuntu image